# VSCode exits while debugging a flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

It seems like vscode is trying to present data in the Locals and/or Watch for a large object but after about 10 seconds, it will kill the app and give the message "Exited (sigterm)" in the debug console. I can pinpoint it to one example where I break on a line immediately after this line:

```
Uint8List inputBytes = Uint8List.fromList(List.filled(100000000, 0));
```

I can see "Locals" spinning around but nothing happens and then the app terminates. Is there a setting that can prevent this somehow? Maybe it can cap the represented data at a certain length instead of trying to print it all out?

(I believe this is a vscode specific problem because when I repeat these steps in Android Studio, it doesn't have this issue)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the debug adapter. It should know this is a list and fetch a paged view of the elements, but it's currently fetching them all. For me it doesn't crash, but it also doesn't respond within several minutes.

I'm working on a fix that will let VS Code page through the data:

[image: VS Code paging through data]

This will ship in an upcoming Dart/Flutter SDK release.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will subscribe to that github issue.